# How can I get my iOS app connected with api?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api, url

I am a beginner in iOS development. I was trying to use an api URl: https://www.arbeitnow.com/api/job-board-api in my job search iOS app. But nothing shows on my app. I tested the URL in POSTMAN and it returns json(but HTML in description part?). I wrote the code:

```
func getResults(completed: @escaping (Result<[Results], ErrorMessage>) -> Void) { 
    let urlString = "https://www.arbeitnow.com/api/job-board-api"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return}    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in    
        if let _ = error {
            completed(.failure(.invalidData))
            return
        }   
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
            completed(.failure(.invalidResponse))
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            completed(.failure(.invalidData))
            return
        } 
        do {
            let deconder = JSONDecoder()
            deconder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            let results = try deconder.decode([Results].self, from: data)
            completed(.success(results))     
        } catch {
            completed(.failure(.invalidData))
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

---

```
struct Results: Codable {
    let slug, companyName, title, resultsDescription: String
    let remote: Bool
    let url: String
    let tags, jobTypes: [String]
    let location: String
    let createdAt: Int
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case slug
        case companyName = "company_name"
        case title
        case resultsDescription = "description"
        case remote, url, tags
        case jobTypes = "job_types"
        case location
        case createdAt = "created_at"
    }
}
```

---

I used the code in HomeViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Home"
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "backgroundMain")
    collectionView.register(SearchViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    setupSearchBar()
    Service.shared.getResults() { [weak self] result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let results):
            print(results)
            self?.jobResults = results
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.collectionView.reloadData()
            }   
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

888

I don't know what is wrong with my code. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Please add the code where you show how you use this.

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint at this line and verify it gets called? `print(results)` ?

Comment: Hi, burnsi. Thank you for reply. I have added the code. Also, I checked the api url. It return json but HTML in "description" part. If I want to show "description" in my app, what should I do? Thank you so much!

Comment: Well theres nothing to do about that. Because the api response contains html in the property.

Comment: I add the breakpoint and it's still not working.

Comment: Does the compiler stop at that breakpoint? Is the response printed in the console?

Comment: And what is `Results` ?

Comment: I have added `Results`

Comment: Try `decode(Results.self, from: data)`

Comment: Your `Results` does not match your JSON at all. Try to create your model from https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: Ways I have tried: 1. add breakpoints; 2. `decode(Results.self, from: data)` -> Cannot convert value of type ...; 3. Recreate model. It still shows nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are discarding all meaningful error information, which will make this hard to diagnose. If you get an `Error` object, you should return that:

```swift
enum WebServiceError: Error {
    case httpError(Data, Int)
}

func getResults(completion: @escaping (Result<[Results], Error>) -> Void) {
    let urlString = "https://www.arbeitnow.com/api/job-board-api"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        completion(.failure(URLError(.badURL)))
        return
    }

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard
            let data = data,
            let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            error == nil
        else {
            completion(.failure(error ?? URLError(.badServerResponse)))
            return
        }

        guard 200 ..< 300 ~= response.statusCode else {
            completion(.failure(WebServiceError.httpError(data, response.statusCode)))
            return
        }

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            let results = try decoder.decode([Results].self, from: data)
            completion(.success(results.data))
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

So, that will,

- if there was a `URLSession` error, tell you what the error was;
- if there was a non-2xx status code, tell you what the code was (and return the body of the response, too, in case you want to look at that); and
- if there was a parsing error, tell you what the parsing error was.

Without something like this, that captures the salient error information, you are flying blind.

---

In this case, the error is that you are parsing for `[Results]`, but the structure is a dictionary, whose key is `data` and whose value is a `[Results]`. You are missing an object for this dictionary that wraps the `[Results]`.

```swift
struct ResponseObject: Decodable {
    let data: [Posting]
    let links: Links
    let meta: Meta
}

struct Posting: Decodable {
    let slug, companyName, title, description: String
    let remote: Bool
    let url: String
    let tags, jobTypes: [String]
    let location: String
    let createdAt: Int
}

struct Links: Decodable {
    let first: URL?
    let last: URL?
    let prev: URL?
    let next: URL?
}

struct Meta: Decodable {
    let currentPage: Int
    let path: URL
    let perPage: Int
    let from: Int
    let to: Int
    let terms: String
    let info: String
}

func getResults(completion: @escaping (Result<[Posting], Error>) -> Void) {
    let urlString = "https://www.arbeitnow.com/api/job-board-api"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        completion(.failure(URLError(.badURL)))
        return
    }

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard
            let data = data,
            let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            error == nil
        else {
            completion(.failure(error ?? URLError(.badServerResponse)))
            return
        }

        guard 200 ..< 300 ~= response.statusCode else {
            completion(.failure(WebServiceError.httpError(data, response.statusCode)))
            return
        }

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            let results = try decoder.decode(ResponseObject.self, from: data)
            completion(.success(results.data))
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply! Could you tell me how to use the code in HomeViewController? My original code `self?.jobResults = results` returns an error says "Cannot assign value of type '[Service.Posting]' to type '[Results]'.

Comment: I changed the name of the `struct` to something meaningful. Use whatever name you want. Clearly,`jobResults` is defined to be a `[Results]`, so you could change it to be `[Posting]` (and move this `Posting` definition to wherever you currently have `Results` defined.

Comment: What I got from console with my original code is:  `GradCareer[42890:1418715] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(151) Failed to log metrics
invalidData`

Comment: Don’t worry about that. That is a logging statement unrelated to your code.

Comment: Thank you! I changed all `Results` to `Posting`. Build succeeded but no job shows in the app. The message got from console is `2022-04-09 17:00:21.796102-0400 GradCareer[43202:1429138] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(151) Failed to log metrics
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "link", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"link\", intValue: nil) (\"link\").", underlyingError: nil))` Could you help me with that?

Comment: Typo in code snippet above. It's `links`, not `link`. Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! I want to vote for you but I don't have 15 reputation Your answer really helped me!

Comment: @ziyiL you now have enough reputation

Answer (score 2):

Your model does not match the JSON you receive from the link you provided:

Using:

```
struct Root: Codable{
   let data: [WorkData]
   let links: Links
   let meta: Meta
}

// MARK: - Links
struct Links: Codable {
    let first: String
    let last, prev: String?
    let next: String
}

// MARK: - Meta
struct Meta: Codable {
    let currentPage, from: Int
    let path: String
    let perPage, to: Int
    let terms, info: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case currentPage = "current_page"
        case from, path
        case perPage = "per_page"
        case to, terms, info
    }
}

struct WorkData: Codable {
    let slug, companyName, title, payloadDescription: String
    let remote: Bool
    let url: String
    let tags, jobTypes: [String]
    let location: String
    let createdAt: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case slug
        case companyName = "company_name"
        case title
        case payloadDescription = "description"
        case remote, url, tags
        case jobTypes = "job_types"
        case location
        case createdAt = "created_at"
    }
}
```

should solve the problem

Usage:

```
let root = JsonDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
let firstCompany = root.data[0]
```

Edit to adress the comment:
This should work!

> let results = try decoder.decode([Results].self, from: data)

is your code isn´t it?

instead use:

```
let root = JsonDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
```

how could data be missing here?

After that you should either map the root object to your `Result` type to keep your Viewmodel and completion Handler the way they are now. Or change Viewmodel and completion Handler instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However, when I write `let root = JsonDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)`, it is said `Cannot find data in scope`. Could you tell me what else should I do?

Comment: @ziyiL see my update.